# HTML DIV Overflowing, How To Stop?

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to achieve: [image]

I'm trying to position three elements alongside each other. Two content boxes with a dividing div in between. I am getting overflow problems with the right content box. It always appears below the two other divs.

It may be a problem with how the centre divider is positioned but I can't think of a better method of positioning it.

Codepen of what I currently have: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNNKpB?editors=110

Here's my CSS:

```
.contact {
height: 300px;
}

.container {
width: 70%;
margin-left: 15%;
margin-right: 15%;
}

.centre-divider {
width: 0.1%;
margin-left: 49.95%;
margin-right: 49.95%;
height: 300px;
background-color: darkgray;
}

.left-contact {
width: 500px;
float: left;
height: 300px;
background-color: lightgray;
}

.right-contact {
float: right;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: Where do you need to use % and where px? If you only use px you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k3y4g3zp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use width in % for `.container` you should use width in % for the child elements. Otherwise, you always will have errors on the different screen size.

The new way of the positioning you want is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) without floats:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    /* ... another styles here */
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWWROr

But if you use flexbox don't forget about browser prefixes, you can get them here http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can add another div inside the `.centre-divider` div which will be the vertical line, then just set a `display: inline-block;` on `.centre-divider`:

```css
body {
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Minion Pro, serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.contact {
  height: 300px;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.centre-divider {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
}

.centre-divider > div {
  width: 1px;
  height: inherit;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left-box {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.right-box {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left-box">

      </div>
      <div class="centre-divider">
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-box">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

You will have to adjust the widths but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Minion Pro, serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.contact {
  height: 300px;
}

.container {
  width: 70%;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.centre-divider {
  width: 0.1%;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.left-box {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.right-box {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display: inline-block;` instead of floating the elements. when you `text-align: center` on the `.contact` div, then the `.left-box`, `.right-box`, and `.centre-divider` are automatically centered in spacing (so you dont have to calculate it yourself, and it still is responsive to the width of the screen.

```css
body {
    font-family: Garamond, serif;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Minion Pro, serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80px;
}

.contact {
    height: 300px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.centre-divider {
    width: 2px;;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: darkgray;
}

.left-box {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.right-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left-box">

      </div>
      <div class="centre-divider"></div>
      <div class="right-box">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```